# rails how to output html class with variable content

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, class, view

I wan to customize the look of the status therefore add html class equal to content like "pending" or delivered

```
<span id="status"><%= @order.status.name, :class =>  %></span>
```

How to add the class?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add the class to the `<span>` tag?

Comment: because I want to apply different style to different values therefore I don't want to have if status = "pending" do ... and repeat X times